# HDD Device WD Black 4TB isn't detected by any Controller

Tags: linux, hard-drive, bios

I bought a new WD Black 4TB HDD and it isn't detected after plugged in my HP ProLiant DL380 Server. 
I just tried it on different PC's and Controllers but the same thing
I've sent the HDD already retoure once.

Here is a dmesg output log from my Linux Kali System, after directly putted in:

```
[Tue Aug 13 06:56:41 2019] ata1: SATA link up 6.0 Gbps (SStatus 133 SControl 300)
[Tue Aug 13 06:56:41 2019] ata1.00: failed to read native max address (err_mask=0x100)
[Tue Aug 13 06:56:41 2019] ata1.00: HPA support seems broken, skipping HPA handling
[Tue Aug 13 06:56:47 2019] ata1: SATA link up 6.0 Gbps (SStatus 133 SControl 300)
[Tue Aug 13 06:56:47 2019] ata1.00: failed to enable AA (error_mask=0x1)
[Tue Aug 13 06:56:47 2019] ata1.00: READ LOG DMA EXT failed, trying PIO
[Tue Aug 13 06:56:47 2019] ata1.00: NCQ Send/Recv Log not supported
[Tue Aug 13 06:56:47 2019] ata1.00: NCQ Send/Recv Log not supported
[Tue Aug 13 06:56:47 2019] ata1.00: ATA-9: WDC WD4005FZBX-00K5WB0, 01.01A01, max UDMA/133
[Tue Aug 13 06:56:47 2019] ata1.00: 7814037168 sectors, multi 0: LBA48 NCQ (depth 32)
[Tue Aug 13 06:56:47 2019] ata1.00: failed to enable Sense Data Reporting, Emask 0x1
[Tue Aug 13 06:56:47 2019] ata1.00: failed to enable AA (error_mask=0x1)
[Tue Aug 13 06:56:47 2019] ata1.00: NCQ Send/Recv Log not supported
[Tue Aug 13 06:56:47 2019] ata1.00: NCQ Send/Recv Log not supported
[Tue Aug 13 06:56:47 2019] ata1.00: failed to enable Sense Data Reporting, Emask 0x1
[Tue Aug 13 06:56:47 2019] ata1.00: configured for UDMA/133 (device error ignored)
[Tue Aug 13 06:56:47 2019] scsi 0:0:0:0: Direct-Access     ATA      WDC WD4005FZBX-0 1A01 PQ: 0 ANSI: 5
[Tue Aug 13 06:56:47 2019] sd 0:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg1 type 0
[Tue Aug 13 06:56:47 2019] sd 0:0:0:0: [sdb] 7814037168 512-byte logical blocks: (4.00 TB/3.64 TiB)
[Tue Aug 13 06:56:47 2019] sd 0:0:0:0: [sdb] Write Protect is off
[Tue Aug 13 06:56:47 2019] sd 0:0:0:0: [sdb] Mode Sense: 00 3a 00 00
[Tue Aug 13 06:56:47 2019] sd 0:0:0:0: [sdb] Write cache: enabled, read cache: enabled, doesn't support DPO or FUA
[Tue Aug 13 06:56:47 2019] ata1: failed to read log page 10h (errno=-5)
[Tue Aug 13 06:56:47 2019] ata1.00: exception Emask 0x1 SAct 0x1000000 SErr 0x0 action 0x0
[Tue Aug 13 06:56:47 2019] ata1.00: irq_stat 0x40000001
[Tue Aug 13 06:56:47 2019] ata1.00: failed command: READ FPDMA QUEUED
[Tue Aug 13 06:56:47 2019] ata1.00: cmd 60/08:c0:00:00:00/00:00:00:00:00/40 tag 24 ncq dma 4096 in
                                    res 41/04:08:00:00:00/00:00:00:00:00/40 Emask 0x1 (device error)
[Tue Aug 13 06:56:47 2019] ata1.00: status: { DRDY ERR }
[Tue Aug 13 06:56:47 2019] ata1.00: error: { ABRT }
[Tue Aug 13 06:56:47 2019] ata1.00: both IDENTIFYs aborted, assuming NODEV
[Tue Aug 13 06:56:47 2019] ata1.00: revalidation failed (errno=-2)
[Tue Aug 13 06:56:47 2019] ata1: hard resetting link
[Tue Aug 13 06:56:47 2019] ata1: SATA link up 6.0 Gbps (SStatus 133 SControl 300)
[Tue Aug 13 06:56:47 2019] ata1.00: failed to enable AA (error_mask=0x1)
[Tue Aug 13 06:56:47 2019] ata1.00: NCQ Send/Recv Log not supported
[Tue Aug 13 06:56:47 2019] ata1.00: NCQ Send/Recv Log not supported
[Tue Aug 13 06:56:47 2019] ata1.00: failed to enable Sense Data Reporting, Emask 0x1
[Tue Aug 13 06:56:47 2019] ata1.00: failed to enable AA (error_mask=0x1)
[Tue Aug 13 06:56:47 2019] ata1.00: NCQ Send/Recv Log not supported
[Tue Aug 13 06:56:47 2019] ata1.00: NCQ Send/Recv Log not supported
[Tue Aug 13 06:56:47 2019] ata1.00: failed to enable Sense Data Reporting, Emask 0x1
[Tue Aug 13 06:56:47 2019] ata1.00: configured for UDMA/133 (device error ignored)
[Tue Aug 13 06:56:47 2019] ata1: EH complete
[Tue Aug 13 06:56:47 2019] ata1: failed to read log page 10h (errno=-5)
[Tue Aug 13 06:56:47 2019] ata1.00: NCQ disabled due to excessive errors
[Tue Aug 13 06:56:47 2019] ata1.00: exception Emask 0x1 SAct 0x8 SErr 0x0 action 0x0
[Tue Aug 13 06:56:47 2019] ata1.00: irq_stat 0x40000001
[Tue Aug 13 06:56:47 2019] ata1.00: failed command: READ FPDMA QUEUED
[Tue Aug 13 06:56:47 2019] ata1.00: cmd 60/08:18:00:00:00/00:00:00:00:00/40 tag 3 ncq dma 4096 in
                                    res 41/04:08:00:00:00/00:00:00:00:00/40 Emask 0x1 (device error)
[Tue Aug 13 06:56:47 2019] ata1.00: status: { DRDY ERR }
[Tue Aug 13 06:56:47 2019] ata1.00: error: { ABRT }
[Tue Aug 13 06:56:47 2019] ata1.00: both IDENTIFYs aborted, assuming NODEV
[Tue Aug 13 06:56:47 2019] ata1.00: revalidation failed (errno=-2)
[Tue Aug 13 06:56:47 2019] ata1: hard resetting link
[Tue Aug 13 06:56:48 2019] ata1: SATA link up 6.0 Gbps (SStatus 133 SControl 300)
[Tue Aug 13 06:56:48 2019] ata1.00: failed to enable AA (error_mask=0x1)
[Tue Aug 13 06:56:48 2019] ata1.00: NCQ Send/Recv Log not supported
[Tue Aug 13 06:56:48 2019] ata1.00: NCQ Send/Recv Log not supported
[Tue Aug 13 06:56:48 2019] ata1.00: failed to enable Sense Data Reporting, Emask 0x1
[Tue Aug 13 06:56:48 2019] ata1.00: failed to enable AA (error_mask=0x1)
[Tue Aug 13 06:56:48 2019] ata1.00: NCQ Send/Recv Log not supported
[Tue Aug 13 06:56:48 2019] ata1.00: NCQ Send/Recv Log not supported
[Tue Aug 13 06:56:48 2019] ata1.00: failed to enable Sense Data Reporting, Emask 0x1
[Tue Aug 13 06:56:48 2019] ata1.00: configured for UDMA/133 (device error ignored)
[Tue Aug 13 06:56:48 2019] ata1: EH complete
[Tue Aug 13 06:56:48 2019] ata1.00: exception Emask 0x0 SAct 0x0 SErr 0x0 action 0x0
[Tue Aug 13 06:56:48 2019] ata1.00: irq_stat 0x40000001
[Tue Aug 13 06:56:48 2019] ata1.00: failed command: READ DMA
[Tue Aug 13 06:56:48 2019] ata1.00: cmd c8/00:08:00:00:00/00:00:00:00:00/e0 tag 18 dma 4096 in
                                    res 51/04:08:00:00:00/00:00:00:00:00/40 Emask 0x1 (device error)
```

Maybe someone can help me with this.
Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

That disk is broken. 
It does react to the first probe command but as soon as the Linux system tries to get additional information (such as drive-capabilities and size) it doesn't respond.
And your other systems run into the same problem.
Effectively the disk is completely unusable.
As it is new it should be still under warranty: either get it replaced by the shop you bought it from or send it in for RMA directly to Western Digital (WD RAM procedures can be found on their website).

Comment: Yes it seems broken, but i sent it also the third time back to the shop and i got everytimes a new one. Very strange thing or just unlucky as well?

Comment: @mncache That sounds really weird. Multiple disks shouldn't fail on several PC's. You really sure you got a different one? Did you check the serial numbers? I'm not accusing that shop, but it isn't unheard off... Go to the Western Digital web-site and download a copy of their disk-test tool. See what that has to say about the drive. It that says it is no good then send it directly to WD RMA.

Comment: ok, it seems not detectable by the testtool.. very frustrating for me :\

Comment: @mncache If even the WD testtool can't see the disk it is most certainly broken. As the chance that 3 disks in row are all faulty (and I presume other disks work on the same SATA port) the shop has a whole batch of bad disks or they gave you the same bad disk back again every time. Anyway: Send it directly to WD for RMA.

Answer (score 0):

For future googlers: I got exactly the same error messages in the log after accidentially dropping a disk to the ground. When you get this errors there is a very high chance that your disk is toast, like the other answer suggests. Before my accident the disk worked perfectly.